# `method_missing': undefined method `devise_modules'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to separate models from an RoR app into a gem. I'm getting an error when I extended the `User` model from the gem for adding [Devise instance methods](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models#devise-instance_method)

I've tried different methods

1. User.class_eval and ModelsGem::User.class_eval
2. Single table inheritance like: `class SuperClass < ModelsGem::User; end`
3. Overriding the model class like `class User < ActiveModel::Base`

None of them worked with devise.. However, I could access methods of User model from the gem in the app and everything is working as expected other than devise.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
rails g devise:views
rails g devise user
```

if we wanna to add sth like first name and last name put it in the db before rake db:migrate

```
 t.string :first_name
 t.string :last_name
```

then `rake db:migrate`

in the user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable, :confirmable

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
end
```

I hope I did solve your problem

Comment: Found the actual issue.. I was loading the gem containing the user model before initializing devise.. which was throwing me the error.. just loaded the gem in an initializer after devise is initialized and it worked! Thanks for method though!